# URL's ID value not persisting to Get Request for a "Product/Create/[Category ID]" Post Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I am trying to build an action for a request in my Controller that will accept a request of the form: `Product/Create/[Category ID]`.

When users are on the `Product/Index/[Category Id]` page, they can see all products specific to that Category ID.

They can click "Create" button which should process the `Get` request: `Product/Create/[Category ID]`. I need to persist the `Category ID` from the previous request into this PostRequest to create products for the specific `Category ID`.

My Controller's Create Actions look like this:

```
public ActionResult Create(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return View(new ProductViewModel{CategoryId = id.Value});
        }

        // POST: Product/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Image,Price,CategoryId")] ProductViewModel viewModel)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid && viewModel.Image != null)
            {
                var category = await db.Categories.FindAsync(viewModel.CategoryId);

                if (category == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }

                category.Products.Add(viewModel);

                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index/" + viewModel.CategoryId);
            }

            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

Also you can see in the Create Action's GetRequest, I try to persist the id into the model's `CategoryId` property. The model in the Create Action's PostRequest is supposed to then contain the value of `CategoryId` it obtained from the GetRequest.

The Model in the View from the `Product/Index/[Category ID]` is a List:

```
@model List<ValueVille.Models.ProductViewModel>
@using MvcApplication8.Models

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p class="btn btn-default">
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", new { id = Model[0].CategoryId})
</p>

<table class="panel panel-default table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].Name)

        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].Image)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].Price)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.Image(item.ByteImage, "Product_Image", "100")
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", new { Controller = "Category" }, new { id = Model[0].Id})
</div>
```

In the same View, the `Create` ActionLink looks like this:

```
<p class="btn btn-default">
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", new { id = Model[0].CategoryId})
</p>
```

In the browser, the `id` always gives the Value of 0, so I am always taken to `Product/Create/0` when clicking `Create` from the `Product/Index/[Category ID]` page.

ProductViewModel class with conversion methods:

```
public class ProductViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required, Display(Name="Product Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
        public HttpPostedFileBase Image { get; set; }
        public string OutputImage { get; set; }
        public Byte[] ByteImage { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Decimal Price { get; set; } 
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        public static byte[] ConvertToByte(ProductViewModel model)
        {
            if (model.Image != null)
            {
                byte[] imageByte = null;
                BinaryReader rdr = new BinaryReader(model.Image.InputStream);
                imageByte = rdr.ReadBytes((int)model.Image.ContentLength);

                return imageByte;
            }

            return null;
        }

        // ViewModel => Model | Implicit type Operator
        public static implicit operator Product(ProductViewModel viewModel)
        {
            var model = new Product
            {
                Id = viewModel.Id,
                Name = viewModel.Name,
                Image = ConvertToByte(viewModel),
                Price = viewModel.Price
            };

            return model;
        }

        // Model => ViewModel | Implicit type Operator
        public static implicit operator ProductViewModel(Product model)
        {
            var viewModel = new ProductViewModel
            {
                Id = model.Id,
                Name = model.Name,
                OutputImage = string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(model.Image)),
                ByteImage = model.Image,
                Price = model.Price,
                CategoryId = model.Id
            };

            return viewModel;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Don't you need to convert your view model into a domain object instead of `category.Products.Add(viewModel);`?

Comment: I have implicit conversion methods inside the ViewModel class which do the conversions. I've included it in my updated question.

Comment: Are you certain that `CategoryId` is being populated in your `Index` controller method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `CategoryId` isn't being populated for whatever reason. I suggest you modify the view model for your index page to explicitly define the category id as a separate property:

```
public class ProductIndexViewModel
{
    public IList<ValueVille.Models.ProductViewModel> Products;
    public int? CategoryId
}
```

Explicitly set the `CategoryId` value in your index action method.

Replace your index view's model definition with:

```
@model ProductIndexViewModel
```

the Create action link with:

```
<p class="btn btn-default">
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", new { id = Model.CategoryId })
</p>
```

and the product loop with:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Products) {
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Chris! :)

Answer (score 1):

*Please include the rest of the view code for `Index.cshtml` in the question.*

I suspect that the issue lies with `new { id = Model[0].CategoryId }`. Assuming that you are displaying a list of all products on the Index page in some form of loop, try using the local product reference rather than an index on the model:

```
@foreach (var p in Model)
{
    ...
    <p class="btn btn-default">
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", new { id = p.CategoryId })
    </p>
    ...
}
```

Comment: I've updated the question and included the index page code

Comment: Ah I see what you are trying to do now, this answer won't resolve it.